# File too large to read in Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Usually I would upload a csv file to google drive, then in Google Colab, mount drive at `/content/drive` and use `pd.read_csv` to read the file.

The uploaded files usually appear under `/content/drive/My Drive/` like this after mounting:

[image]

This time I uploaded a csv file of 2GB in size but could not find it in the `/content/drive/My Drive/` section in order to open it. I checked a few posts but didn't seem to solve my problem. Is there a way I can read the large csv file?

---

Update:

Upon trying to get the sharable link with `edit` right, it appeared there was no option for `edit`, as shown below:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try an alternative method to mounting drive.

```
!gdown --id xxxxxxxxxxx
```

This will download the file from GDrive to the current directory.

You need to share the file publicly, and get the ID (xxxxxx) from the shared URL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried `!gdown --id https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GNjhogITyxMiaLno4trJoGM6I-MofFG8/view?usp=sharing`, but it returned `Permission denied: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GNjhogITyxMiaLno4trJoGM6I-MofFG8/view?usp=sharing
Maybe you need to change permission over 'Anyone with the link'?`and as I checked the edit right setting, there was no `edit` option as opposed to `view`

Comment: Try !gdown --id 1GNjhogITyxMiaLno4trJoGM6I-MofFG8

Answer (score 1):

As @korakot mentioned, you can use the following command to download the file from your drive to the current directory in Colab Pro using the following command:

`!gdown --id 1GNjhogITyxMiaLno4trJoGM6I-MofFG8`

This assumes that the file is made shareable in Drive.

If you receive the `Permission Denied` error and have verified that the file is indeed shareable, you have unfortunately reached a quota. This happens when large files in Drive are accessed too frequently in a 24 hour period. I experienced this recently with a very large file and was able to access it after waiting a day or so.

To get around this, there is a thread around this topic in the Colab GitHub, and a potential solution to download the file in chunks in [this comment specifically](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1607#issuecomment-727073152).